# Is there a way to "turn off" installed Windows Updates?

Tags: windows-8.1, keyboard

So I have a ASUS N550JK laptop with media keys - I recently factory reset it and all my Fn Keys were working (like the ones to change brightness/volume etc.) I installed a slew of Windows Updates and now my Media Fn Keys no longer work (I can't Play/Pause, Skip Track, Prev Track, Stop a song with my keyboard).

I was wondering if there's a way to go back and "turn off" the installed updates on my machine to figure out exactly which update broke my keys? For the record I'm running Windows 8.1

Comment: Just uninstall them unless you performed the command to clean up your installation then it cannot be done.

Comment: @Ramhound is there a way to batch uninstall or must I do it one-by-one because there's a lot of them

Comment: You can do that through PowerShell if you want to.